# Need regex for String contrains digit with starting letter p in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript regular expression , i tried below expression for string and digit with starting letter p and remaining digit

`p1749350502`

where p is constant and remaining digits are variable
i tried this expression but failed to identify

```
p^[0-9]$
```

Please help is this regular expression is correct or not

Comment: You can use: `/^p[0-9]+$/`

Answer (score 4):

You can use following regex

```
/^p[0-9]+$/
```

1. `^`: Beginning of line
2. `p`: Match `p` alphabet
3. `[0-9]+`: Match one or more digits
4. `$`: End of line

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the start anchor `^` before `p` and use `+` modifier after your character class (which makes it matches 1 or more digits):

```
/^p[0-9]+$/
```

Read more http://www.regular-expressions.info/